Why does Jenkins require root if Jenkinsfile is in subdirectory?
I experienced an issue where if I run a Jenkinsfile from the root directory, then I am able to run the following with no issues, but if I specify that it is in a sub directory; e.g. src/demo-dir/Jenkinsfile then I encounter permission errors. Can anyone explain why that is?
> Error: 
> npm verb cli /usr/bin/node /usr/bin/npm
> 
> npm info using npm@10.2.4
> 
> npm info using node@v20.11.1
> 
> npm verb title npm install
> 
> npm verb argv "install" "--loglevel" "verbose"
> 
> npm verb logfile logs-max:10 dir:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/qa-gryph-load-test-prod/.npm/_logs/2024-04-09T00_03_00_112Z-
> 
> npm verb logfile could not be created: Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/qa-gryph-load-test-prod/.npm/_logs/2024-04-09T00_03_00_112Z-debug-0.log'
> 
> npm verb logfile no logfile created
> 
> npm verb stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/qa-gryph-load-test-prod/.npm/_cacache/tmp/ab3ad9ff'
> 
> npm verb cwd /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/qa-gryph-load-test-prod
> 
> npm verb Linux 4.9.0-13-amd64
> 
> npm verb node v20.11.1
> 
> npm verb npm  v10.2.4
> 
> npm ERR! code EACCES
> 
> npm ERR! syscall open
> 
> npm ERR! path /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/qa-gryph-load-test-prod/.npm/_cacache/tmp/ab3ad9ff
> 
> npm ERR! errno -13
> 
> npm verb Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/qa-gryph-load-test-prod/.npm/_cacache/tmp/ab3ad9ff' 
> 
> npm ERR! 
> 
> npm ERR! Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in
> 
> npm ERR! previous versions of npm which has since been addressed.
> 
> npm ERR! 
> 
> npm ERR! To permanently fix this problem, please run:
> 
> npm ERR!   sudo chown -R 109:114 "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/qa-gryph-load-test-prod/.npm"
> 
> npm verb exit -13
> 
> npm verb unfinished npm timer command:install 1712620980480
> 
> npm verb unfinished npm timer reify 1712620980483
> 
> npm verb unfinished npm timer reify:loadTrees 1712620980526
> 
> npm verb unfinished npm timer idealTree 1712620980527
> 
> npm verb unfinished npm timer idealTree:buildDeps 1712620980856
> 
> npm verb unfinished npm timer idealTree:#root 1712620980856
> 
> npm verb code -13
> 
> 
> 
> npm ERR! Log files were not written due to an error writing to the directory: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/qa-gryph-load-test-prod/.npm/_logs
> 
> npm ERR! You can rerun the command with `--loglevel=verbose` to see the logs in your terminal
> 
> script returned exit code 243

Sample pipeline script:
pipeline {
  agent {
    docker {
      image 'mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.42.0-focal'
      args "-v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd"
    }
  }
  parameters {
    /*
     * NODE_ENV = Indicates which properties file to run.
     */
    string(name: 'NODE_ENV', defaultValue: 'prod', description: 'environment to target')
    booleanParam(name: 'RUN_ARTILLERY_REPORT', defaultValue: false, description: 'key for reporting')
  }
  environment {
    HOME = '.'
    JENKINS_RUN = 'true'
  }
  stages {
    stage('Checkout SCM') {
      steps {
        checkout scm
      }
    }
    stage('Dependencies') {
      steps {
        sh 'npm install  --loglevel verbose'
      }
    }
    stage('Load Test') {
      steps {
        sh """                                  
          npx artillery run -e ${params.NODE_ENV} 'src/load-test/load-test.yml' --record --key  xxxxxxxxxxxxx
        """
      }
    }
  }
  post {
    always {                          
      archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'src/load-test/report.json' // Optional: Archive report
    }
  }
}

I have changed the directories to verify that it only occurs in subdirectories and I have run as root to confirm that it is an permissions issues.

Could you check without declaring HOME = '.'?

@AlexanderPletnev Thanks for weighing in. Removing <HOME= '.'>  has not effect and as long as the root user is set in the docker args. I am able to run successfully. Without it and remove the root user in args, then the error message changes slightly. npm verb Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir/.npm'
npm ERR! Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in
npm ERR! previous versions of npm which has since been addressed.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To permanently fix this problem, please run:
npm ERR!   sudo chown -R 109:114 "/.npm"
npm verb exit -13
`

That makes sense. Generally, the container should be considered immutable, and if it's implemented well - it is immutable. You should bind mount the cache directories from the build agent, like args: '-v /home/jenkins/.npm:/home/default/.npm' (names and paths could differ in your case). So I highly doubt that the issue is somehow related to the location of the Jenkinsfile itself, but I wouldn't be surprised if playing with the HOME location could affect the overall behavior.
